# String содержит запись PKCS7 как привести в читабельный вид

Tags: java, строки

Привет уважаемое комьюнити, 
есть некоторый код на Java, сей код включает в себя переменную типа String, которая в свою хранит следующее содержимое:

```
0,-----BEGIN PKCS7-----
MIIIzwYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIIwDCCCLwCAQExDzANBglghkgBZQMEAgEFADALBgkqhkiG9w0BBwGg
ggZbMIIGVzCCBT+gAwIBAgIELhJ2QDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCBmDELMAkGA1UEBhMCREUxEDAO
BgNVBAoMB1NpZW1lbnMxETAPBgNVBAUTCFpaWlpaWlkyMTowOAYDVQQLDDFDb3B5cmlnaHQgKEMp
IFNpZW1lbnMgQUcgMjAxMyBBbGwgUmlnaHRzIFJlc2VydmVkMSgwJgYDVQQDDB9TaWVtZW5zIElz
c3VpbmcgQ0EgRUUgQXV0aCAyMDEzMB4XDTE0MDcxODEzNTcwM1oXDTE3MDcxODEzNTcwM1owYzER
MA8GA1UEBRMIWjAwMzBBTUgxDzANBgNVBCoMBkFsZXhleTERMA8GA1UEBAwIU2Vkb3lraW4xEDAO
BgNVBAoMB1NpZW1lbnMxG,DAWBgNVBAMMD1NlZG95a2luIEFsZXhleTCCASAwCwYJKoZIhvcNAQEB
A4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQCKahNgWzDPSnOwba2ljWQb8LniuvAGZHEvdd5zm8H7Kw56WMxdixKHoKSC
hXWf1zGE3RZAsQOdHOpcgiqnRF2xLe2lLjCLoE9sC4DfUVD4mKe3kcxtnsxkoLc1A/3QXJSOzpk7
rPJeqehmuj06yCtPjpdFGmtf4bkskiQuK8u4RJfnmzffWQppd2Ld+u8tLxQKyHnZtOnPyYQGRQJX
JKhruDnnLonlveVXKzEzmo88E5udB+/6jDWDfuyfKHMFyOhk80qGeYDOYQHxiq/PJbAyQU6XPONb
fsCgILKxx7uHaBlhNALxjFZSeNNtfg0bx82O1DoJEcWcOjZQtQMuNUjvAgMBAAGjggLdMIIC2TAd
BgNVHQ4EFgQUE5jDSnfWWnlUWMKztQ6zYfgohUkwUwYDVR0RBEwwSqArBgorBgEEA,YI3FAIDoB0M
G2FsZXhleS5zZWRveWtpbkBzaWVtZW5zLmNvbYEbYWxleGV5LnNlZG95a2luQHNpZW1lbnMuY29t
MA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIHgDCCAQQGCCsGAQUFBwEBBIH3MIH0MDIGCCsGAQUFBzAChiZodHRwOi8v
YWguc2llbWVucy5jb20vcGtpP1paWlpaWlkyLmNydDBBBggrBgEFBQcwAoY1bGRhcDovL2FsLnNp
ZW1lbnMubmV0L0NOPVpaWlpaWlkyLEw9UEtJP2NBQ2VydGlmaWNhdGUwSQYIKwYBBQUHMAKGPWxk
YXA6Ly9hbC5zaWVtZW5zLmNvbS9DTj1aWlpaWlpZMixvPVRydXN0Y2VudGVyP2NBQ2VydGlmaWNh
dGUwMAYIKwYBBQUHMAGGJGh0dHA6Ly9vY3NwLnBraS1zZXJ2aWNlcy5zaWVtZW5zLmNvbTAfBgNV
HSMEGDAWgBTelD9Lal9YThQYyUbXFDn,CnCE8KTAMBgNVHRMBAf8EAjAAMBoGA1UdIAQTMBEwDwYN
KwYBBAGhaQcCAgMBATCBygYDVR0fBIHCMIG/MIG8oIG5oIG2hiZodHRwOi8vY2guc2llbWVucy5j
b20vcGtpP1paWlpaWlkyLmNybIZBbGRhcDovL2NsLnNpZW1lbnMubmV0L0NOPVpaWlpaWlkyLEw9
UEtJP2NlcnRpZmljYXRlUmV2b2NhdGlvbkxpc3SGSWxkYXA6Ly9jbC5zaWVtZW5zLmNvbS9DTj1a
WlpaWlpZMixvPVRydXN0Y2VudGVyP2NlcnRpZmljYXRlUmV2b2NhdGlvbkxpc3QwMwYDVR0lBCww
KgYIKwYBBQUHAwIGCCsGAQUFBwMEBgorBgEEAYI3FAICBggrBgEFBQgCAjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUF
AAOCAQEAmzrYxmkRuSPMitK0rnR98BXlnB88ldVXjyz+rjHg9QghoZ5+8u7wHnxMSXida4XvYbh,N
5maUQs3DdWebvXP6CXt/OErVgYHlEAT8d5iqvin7/6eEgS0ge9DOxD2Rv+LYltPmAsjgxUS/0Mec
bUJpyBct6mDNfPI7riCu+mCcw6v9OKLWnXTIZsV9Z/WqaFbqVeJ5wo1+MUGWCGrDVkn7XnCKAQN8
xEEO+Dq/TSVyv8tlDUzWps1yb3l9cYDc030s5AwFXa99v76pYJUZ08qQsieXOrs3qyQxMalM/Y04
2N17bwf9XkGT6iKN8o8U0YS1Vkaz8iroBRKkiA2pRNN4AjGCAjgwggI0AgEBMIGhMIGYMQswCQYD
VQQGEwJERTEQMA4GA1UECgwHU2llbWVuczERMA8GA1UEBRMIWlpaWlpaWTIxOjA4BgNVBAsMMUNv
cHlyaWdodCAoQykgU2llbWVucyBBRyAyMDEzIEFsbCBSaWdodHMgUmVzZXJ2ZWQxKDAmBgNVBAMM
H1NpZW1lbnMgSXNzdWluZyBDQSBFRSBBdXRoIDIwM,TMCBC4SdkAwDQYJYIZIAWUDBAIBBQCgaTAY
BgkqhkiG9w0BCQMxCwYJKoZIhvcNAQcBMBwGCSqGSIb3DQEJBTEPFw0xNzA1MDMxNDI3NTFaMC8G
CSqGSIb3DQEJBDEiBCBCA/fR9wGftKzKFZRuIDJVbYiaHzsDteoUoUL55kMrYDANBgkqhkiG9w0B
AQEFAASCAQA6HtP3xr36VLj+WMaoPRrszLfMJTE7lKIX3Vjybj2W3yj4qanPamZBb4KyEDIvQA8r
65j4dbzcDePoFsRB5eYRnfB/djuXPAZdL9xdFMH3iRzfcseSFXulZ8FrG/9cuqDQkYVIx/Fk43yL
tlpxOncVG3vZVW306yKQLu7Tsy+/GEkNDBMt6akqNPWp+9zqQTj7TaCXg7qr7mTlSStZE15USoAO
elisALpwPdizvfaJOqP03IobwDXMfRaCjzEANVl/M3woL1sNLu6BtuMemAdls8tnJWDF+wpD4Y25
6Dso4Fv,De2iK923jNElzq4iyc6ZosqGORS3nTh/1FQypgkC1
-----END PKCS7-----
```

Нужно сие привести в читабильный вид, на манер того как это делает on-line ресуры (https://certlogik.com/decoder/)
Спасибо за любые идеи!

Comment: Вы эту строку куда-то выводите и вам надо вывести её колонкой фиксированной ширины?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev мне нужно её распарсить и вывести просто в консоль

Comment: Чего её парсить, если это монотонная строка символов? Тем более, как следует из вопроса, он уже сохранена в переменной.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev эти символы - публичный ключ цифровой подписи.

Comment: Можете быть уверены, я это заметил.